# How to find if NSTimer is active or not?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0, nstimer, invalidation

I have a timer something like this:

```
 NSTimer* timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                                   target:self
                                                 selector:@selector(updateCountdown)
                                                 userInfo:nil
                                                  repeats:YES];
```

I am updating a label's text using this timer. At a certain condition, I want to check if the timer is active then invalidate the timer. My question is how do I find that timer is active or not?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

When a non repeating timer fires it marks itself as invalid so you can check whether it is still valid before cancelling it (and of course then ridding yourself of it).

```
if ( [timer isValid] && yourOtherCondition){
    [timer invalidate], timer=nil;
}
```

In your case you have a repeating timer so it will always be valid until you take some action to invalidate it. Looks like in this case you are running a countdown so it will be up to you to make sure you invalidate and rid yourself of it when the countdown reaches the desired value (In your updateCountdown method)

Comment: Awesome example! Thanks

Answer (score 8):

`NSTimer` has an `-isValid` method.

Answer (score 5):

Keep the timer in an instance variable, and set `timer = nil` when there's no timer running (i.e. after you call `[timer invalidate]`).  Then, to check if the timer is active, you can just check whether `timer == nil`.

Answer (score 1):

In Swift, you can use the `isValid` boolean to see if the timer is running:

```
if timer.isValid {
   // Do stuff
}
```

From the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/):

> A Boolean value that indicates whether the receiver is currently
> valid. (read-only)
>
> true if the receiver is still capable of firing or false if the timer has been
> invalidated and is no longer capable of firing.